# How to install dcop?

Tags: command-line, kde, cinnamon, yakuake

I tried to run `dcop`, since my *yakuake* cannot be shown again in my Cinnamon, and I don't want to restart my yakuake. I found that this command can make my yakuake show again:

```
dcop yakuake DCOPInterface slotToggleState
```

But I got no luck running it:

```
$ dcop
No command 'dcop' found, did you mean:
 Command 'dtop' from package 'diod' (universe)
 Command 'dccp' from package 'dcap' (universe)
 Command 'bcop' from package 'compiz-fusion-bcop' (universe)
dcop: command not found
```

I've tried to search it, but no luck:

```
$ apt-cache search dcop
courier-filter-perl - purely Perl-based mail filter framework for the Courier MTA
gambas3 - Complete visual development environment for Gambas
grace - XY graphing and plotting tool
jless - A file pager program, similar to more(1) supporting ISO2022
konversation - user friendly Internet Relay Chat (IRC) client for KDE
xgraph - Plotting program, reads stdin, allows interactive zooming
```

So, in which package `dcop` application is contained?

Comment: What's dcop exactly? It seems not to be packaged in Ubuntu. Can you point to a web page or source?

Comment: Desktop COmmunication Protocol en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCOP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### It's obsolete and has been removed

DCOP the protocol is now being handled by D-Bus, the former `dcop` command is an old KDE thing.

It's even in the [Wikipedia: DCOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCOP) page you provided yourself!

> DCOP was replaced by D-Bus in KDE Software Compilation 4.
>
> [...]
>
> D-Bus, a message bus system standardized by freedesktop.org, was heavily influenced by the DCOP system and replaces DCOP in KDE Software Compilation 4.

So, have a look at the possibilities the `dbus-*` commands can do for you.

I think you were looking at a very old or mixed up sources, as Cinnamon is quite new thing while this has been obsoleted since the release of KDE 4 in 2008.

#### Move to D-Bus

In KDE, to toggle the window state of Yakuake Terminal emulator, do this (verified working):

```
qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/window toggleWindowState
```

How to get this working in Cinnamon? Not sure, as Yakuake is a KDE program and I'm not familiar with non-Qt D-Bus implementations.

Comment: ok many thanks.. i've found the dbus (qdbus command) but it's not working.. so i give up for now.. XD

Comment: @KiswonoPrayogo Try the command I used. While still not clear what you wanted to accomplish to start with, this example is working for me. The `slotToggleState` state seems not available as an option to  `/yakuake/window`.

Comment: no, it's not working.. | the problem: sometimes KDE global shortcut stopped working, so i can't call yakuake back, even by calling yakuake from gnome-console again.. it wont show up..

Comment: @KiswonoPrayogo What do you mean "it's not working"? Do you get an error message? Does Yakuake do something else? What *exact* command did you try? etc.

Comment: no, just empty output, and the yakuake window not shown.. | qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/window toggleWindowState

Comment: @KiswonoPrayogo then I'm lost as to what is different in your set up. You could try debugging and finding another way using `qdbusviewer`, e.g. the `raiseSession` method.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ubuntu Package Search : http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=lucid&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=dcop

It is contain in kdelibs until lucid (Ubuntu 10.04).

Comment: This is the completion hinting *on* dcop as far as I can see.

Comment: @gertvdijk good point, re-do search.